# Calling python compiled files in Python 3

Tags: python, pyc, execfile

I have multiple Python versions installed (2.7 and 3.4)
I want to run a .pyc with specified version of Python

```
#! C:\python34\python
import sys
print("Hello",sys.version.split()[0])
input()
```

This sheebang works fine on Windows because I use [pylauncher](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/)
So I can compile like that

```
c:\python34\python -m compileall print.py -b
```

But the sheebang is not recognized when I execute the pyc file.

This works, but I wouldn't like to repeat the `C:\python34\python`
Because the current script will be already running under the Python version I asked in the shebang. 
Therefore I would like to make the sub program start with the same version of the Python.

So far, I tried:

```
#! C:\python34\python
import os
os.system("C:\python34\python print.pyc")
```

This would be perfect, but doesn't  like pyc files. And the following doesn't works either:

```
exec( open('print.pyc').read() )
```

Does someone knows how to call the pyc files in the code?

Comment: have you tried: **os.system("C:\\python34\\python print.pyc")** ?

Comment: No because that I want is not to repeat C:\python34\python since my shebang works fine. I want to say: Run that pyc file in the same already running python's version.

Comment: Can you formulate your question better? You said : **os.system("C:\python34\python print.pyc")** would be fine but it doesn't *like pyc.* While it clearly doesn't have the right backslashes (\\ instead of \ ) in the string.

Comment: It works with "C:\\python34\\python print.pyc", with "C:\\\python34\\\python print.pyc", with "C:/python34/python print.pyc" and with "C:\python34\python print.pyc". But since the path is ok whith the shebang, I dan't want to repeat it.

Comment: Have you tried os.system(sys.executable+" print.pyc") ? sys.executable is path to python executable that is running just now.

Comment: Seems to be ok. Not simpler, but ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! C:\python34\python
import print # imports print.pyc


#now you can use the pyc as a module. 
DoSomething()
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect:

Comment: @Baghera, if this answer is what you were looking for, please accept it.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect:<br/>

    #! C:\python34\python
    import print

This is the run.py file.<br/>
It starts the print.pyc application with the Python's version I want to, because I compiled this application with.<br/>
Thanks